# Are any crew skills profitable on their own without the GTN in SW:TOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Are any crew skills profitable on their own without the GTN in SW:TOR?

I am speaking of both crafting and missions. Are any of the crew skills (in any combination) generally profitable (making more credits than the missions cost) at the highest tier, without selling rewarded/crafted goods on the GTN to other players? How much of a margin can be made this way if your skills are at 400?

(Note: I realize that *more* credits can be made by crafting in-demand items and selling them with a huge markup, but this question is about avoiding the GTN and selling the results to ordinary vendors.)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid GTN?

Comment: Gathering has no costs, so it's obviously profitable.  I'm just going to edit that out.

Comment: @svick Now that I've read Matthew Read's answer, I *don't* want to avoid the GTN. I was trying to gauge whether it was necessary to use the GTN to make a profit from crew skills. Now that I've read Matthew's answer, this is clearly the case. That is what I was trying to determine with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not even close.

Take for example the Treasure Hunting missions [Toxic Knowledge](http://www.torhead.com/crew-mission/76oz9a9/toxic-knowledge) and [Untouched Ruins](http://www.torhead.com/crew-mission/zWWAT/untouched-ruins), which are the highest yield Grade 6 missions that show up without a mission discovery.  Each of these normally returns 2-4 color crystals and 0-2 Lorrdian Gemstones, plus 2 color crystals and 2 Corusca Gems for a crit.  (I kept personal stats on these for a while.)

Let's assume a very high (and nonexistent) crit rate of 50%, so we average 1 Corusca gem each time plus about 5 other mats.  A Corusca gem is worth about 2x as much so we get the equivalent of 7 basic mats per mission.  The sell for ~120 credits each, for 840 credits total.  The missions cost more than double that!

I haven't crunched the numbers specifically but crafted goods seem to vendor for less than the cost of their materials.

Comment: What about using Slicing directly for credits?

Comment: @svick It's closer, but you still lose money without Mission Discoveries.  If you skip the missions and just do gathering then it should be better than gathering and selling materials.

Comment: I haven't played SWTOR in quite awhile, but I seem to remember crafted items sold for exactly the sum of their components.  The right slicing missions also made you a small profit in the long run, once you factored in the crit successes.

Comment: Slicing anything less than Bountiful lockboxes gives you back less money than the mission cost except on a critical success. Exclusively using Rich yield lockbox missions will net a small profit -- significantly less than what you'd get for spending the same amount of time running around killing mobs and then selling the vendor thrash.

Answer (score 0):

Crafting seems to yield less on the gtn as items collected during gameplay are better than those crafted.   For instance... as a level 450 armormech, my purple/artifact gear is significantly underpowered to the Customizable gear given in Orican missions that everyone is selling.  Why gather resources and run Underworld trading missions and craft/reengineer items that come up short?  Not saying you can't make money with certain crafts at lower levles but at the highest levels/end game they are pretty much useless.

I believe the best idea is to gather resources for useful crafts (scavenging & bionalysis) and sell them on the gtn.For non-gtn, use slicing and strictly gather with that. Resources sell back for nothing at vendors....they only sell big on the gtn for people leveling crafts like cybertech or biochem that are useful at all levels.  A third best gather imho is archeology.  FYI only one of my 16 toons on the served has archeology.